# convergence of the series for $p>0$ , $\sum n^p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> Discuss the convergence of the series for $p>0$ ,  $$\sum n^p\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\right)$$

I tried through ratio test. But it fails. I think it will be by comparison test. But I am unable to apply..

Comment: @Misakov Thats not true  $2^p\left(1-\frac 1{\sqrt 2}\right)+3^p\left(\frac 1{\sqrt 2}-\frac 1{\sqrt 3}\right)+\cdots$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n-1}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\sim \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Use the limit comparison test with $\frac 1{n^{3/2}}$ as Michael Galuza suggests.

Comment: Hmmm, why post this?

Comment: Wasn't sure if the OP knew to use the limit comparison test.